# insert of not exists else update Java Mongo 3.0

Tags: java, mongodb

I know this question was asked before and answered with the $upsert option. Which is now no longer available???

Insert is easy enough, but how to update a document if exists and insert if not exists? I tried various approaches to no avail.

The last thing I tried was using collection.updateOne(..) which takes two parameters of type Bson. So, then you'll have to convert an object int Bson using toBsonDocument( ), but what parameters need to be passed to that? An example with 3.0 would be great...

My temporary and workaround is to find and of not available insertOne else updateOne...

Comment: I was looking to apply the $upsert modifier, and that doesn't work. However this does work: <code>db.genres.update({short:"POP"}, {$set: {descr:"Pop Music"}}, {upsert: true} )</code> should be translated into: <code>BasicDBObject action = new BasicDBObject("$set", doc);
  UpdateOptions options = new UpdateOptions();
  options.upsert(true);

  db.genres.updateOne(filter, action, options);</code>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is strange because in the API Documentation 3.0 , the upsert option still exist. DBCollection#update

Edit:
ok i guess you are using the MongoCollection...you should use the [updateOne](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/async/client/MongoCollection.html#updateOne-org.bson.conversions.Bson-org.bson.conversions.Bson-com.mongodb.client.model.UpdateOptions-com.mongodb.async.SingleResultCallback-) method with the [UpdateOptions](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/index.html?_ga=1.106121411.1501635810.1427825062) set to true.